# Continuous synchronization

Tags: backup, sync

I am new to Linux so forgive my ignorance. I am looking to set up a mirror of my data drive. It contains photos, music and my backups from the various PC's in the home. I use a standard 12.10 desktop as my file server. I have my data and the mirror on two identical drives.

I want something that can run in the background to keep the data disk and the mirror in sync. I have tried Grsync and it does the initial copy fine but does not sync again until I hit the "Go" again. Is there a way to set this up to run continuously in the back ground. I use Yadis!Backup on window and it does exactly What I am after.

Thanks

Comment: do you want syncing as a backup solution? be careful though. Everything you delete will (depending on your settings) be deleted on target drives as well. If you really want syncing (and not making backups) and if you don't mind spending a little for more storage, UbuntuOne has excellent syncing features.

Answer (score 2):

A good way to do this is to use the power of CRON. Thankfully, [Ubuntu is very well documented about CRON jobs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto).

You can use a graphical interface to create jobs that do certain things for you via `sudo apt-get install gnome-schedule` (this might be easier). You might need to delve into the terminal side of things so you know which commands to execute for a CRON job, here is an image example:

[image]

So you would need to execute a command in order for this to happen. A local backup could be something along the lines of `sudo rsync -azvv /home/path/folder1/ /home/path/folder2`.

Hope this gets you started in the right direction!